# Representation of an N player game with 2 strategies per player as a matrix and its properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, game-theory, paper-request

Is there any well-studied representation of a N player game with 2 strategies per player as a matrix?

Intuitively, I think that each strategy can be represented as a binary digit, and each strategy profile can be represented as a binary number with the LSB representing the strategy employed by the first player (player 0).

For example, a profile with player 2 playing strategy 1, player 1 playing 0, and player 0 playing 1 would be $101$.

The payoff function would then be a function mapping $\{x \: | \: 0 \leq x \leq 2^N - 1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$, where $N$ is the number of players.

This can be encoded into a matrix, where each column is the payoff for playing the strategy provided by the column number in binary.

The example of the prisoner's dilemma is easy to illustrate:

$
\; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;A\\
B
\begin{bmatrix}
(3, 3) & (10, 1) \\
(1, 10) & (2, 2)
\end{bmatrix}
$

where each index is $(x, y)$, where $x$ describes the payoff to A, and $y$ describes the payoff to B.

The matrix to describe this would look like:

$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 10 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 1 & 10 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$

Is this described in literature? If not, is there an alternative? And what are the spectral properties of such a matrix?